# Bash: Parse CSV and edit cell values

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv

I am new to bash scripting
I have the following CSV

Input

```
ID Location Way Day DayTime NightTime StandNo
1  abc      Up  mon 6.00     18.00    6
```

Expected Output

```
ID Location Way Day DayTime NightTime StandNo
1  ABC      UP  Mon 6.00     18.00    6
```

I need to check Location and Way and convert them to UpperCase - ABC, UP
Day needs to be mon - Mon
I need to do this for entire CSV. I need to correct the value and write all the fields on to CSV or edit the current cell and save CSV
My script is as follows

```
file = "Myfile.csv"
while IFS="," read line
do
output=`echo $line | cut -d "," -f2`
echo $output
for i in $output
do
if [ -z $(echo $I | sed -e "s/[a-z]//g") ]
then 
echo $I | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]" >> ".tempfile.CSV"
fi
done
done <$file
```

`1. Currently this writes only the corrected value and not entire line along with corrected value. [Unsure how I can loop thru cell values in every row correct the ones which needs correction and then copy the entire row]

Any help would be useful.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Learn to use http://shellcheck.net **before** you post your code here ;-) . When you use shellcheck, you need to include a proper "she-bang" line as the first line, usually `#!/bin/bash`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

As question is tagged `linux`, assuming `GNU sed` is available. And also that the input is actually `csv`, not space/tab separated

```
$ cat ip.csv 
ID,Location,Way,Day,DayTime,NightTime,StandNo
1,abc,Up,mon,6.00,18.00,6
2,xyz,down,TUE,2.32,5.23,4

$ sed '2,$ {s/[^,]*/\L\u&/4; s/[^,]*/\U&/3; s/[^,]*/\U&/2}' ip.csv 
ID,Location,Way,Day,DayTime,NightTime,StandNo
1,ABC,UP,Mon,6.00,18.00,6
2,XYZ,DOWN,Tue,2.32,5.23,4
```

- `2,$` to process input from 2nd line to end of file
- `s/[^,]*/\L\u&/4` capitalize only first letter of 4th field
- `s/[^,]*/\U&/3` capitalize all letters in 3rd field
- `s/[^,]*/\U&/2` capitalize all letters in 2nd field

If the fields themselves can contain `,` within double quotes and so on, use `perl`, `python`, etc which has `csv` modules

Comment: Hi Sundeep,
It worked on Gedit :). Thanks. The issue was with MobaXterm editor. Can I knw how \L\u indicates capitalize first letter in a word?

Comment: `\L` will lowercase all letters.... `\u` will uppercase only one letter... if your input has only words like `mon`, `tue` etc, you can skip using `\L`

Comment: Thanks, I got another doubt. If you want me to open another thread I ll do so. I got this case sometimes where in 100, West Bengal, Up, Thu, , , ,.
101, , , Fri, 6.00, 8.00, P3.  I ve this expression s/,[[:blank:]]*,/,,/. This works fine. But when more than 1 blank space exists between delimiters it does not work

Comment: For ex 100, West Bengal, , , , , yields 100, West Bengal,, , , - the space exists between last two delimiters. [Note space needs to be preserved between words like West Bengal]

Comment: not sure about your doubt.. are you trying to delete all blanks in empty fields? if so, you'll need something like `echo '100, West Bengal, , , , ,' | sed ':a s/,[[:blank:]]\+,/,,/; ta'`

Answer (score 1):

Recall in bash, you have a *parameter expansion* that will convert all characters in a variable (e.g. `$line`) to *upper-case*. The form of the expansion is `${line^^}` (note the `'^^'`). To read and convert all characters in lines after the first to upper-case, you can do:

```
declare -i c=0
while read -r line; do 
    if [ "$c" -gt '0' ]; then 
        echo "${line^^}"          ## output line converted to upper
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
    ((c++))
done < file.txt
```

**Example Output**

```
$ declare -i c=0; while read -r line; do if [ "$c" -gt '0' ]; then \ 
echo "${line^^}"; else echo "$line"; fi; ((c++)); done < file.txt
ID Location Way Day DayTime NightTime StandNo
1  ABC      UP  MON 6.00     18.00    6
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a headerless CSV file in input:

```
$ cat file.csv 
1,abc,Up,mon,6.00,18.00,6
```

I'm also assuming you want a CSV file in output.

If all these assumptions are correct, then:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$2=toupper($2); $4=toupper(substr($4,1,1)) substr($4,2); print}' file.csv
1,ABC,Up,Mon,6.00,18.00,6
```

**EDIT**.
If you want to preserve your header line...

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{if(NR>1){$2=toupper($2); $4=toupper(substr($4,1,1)) substr($4,2)} print}' file.csv
ID,Location,Way,Day,DayTime,NightTime,StandNo
1,ABC,Up,Mon,6.00,18.00,6
```

Comment: Header needs to be copied. Can I knw where exactly this line needs to be inserted. Currently it gives me an error saying "multi call binary' Usage:awk [options] [awk_program] [file]... -v var=val set variable

Comment: @MeghnaSathyanarayan: don't understand what you mean with inserted. The command line here above has to be executed (not inserted).

Comment: Apologies Mauro, I reframe my question. I did execute the command and found the error. I thought probably it should be added somewhere in the existing script. I am quite new to bash and hence I may have jumbled up.